# Why is a UIToolBar's height not being taken into account by bottomLayoutGuide and automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets in iOS7 (with autolayout)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I haven't been to find anything about this, and it may be that there is no easy solution.

I have a scroll view (in this instance a *UITableView*) which is the first subview of my *UIViewController*'s view (which is not itself a scroll view). This view controller is in a *UINavigationController*, and I have also added a *UIToolBar* as second subview of the view controller's view. Both the table view and the toolbar are positioned and sized in the view controller's view using autolayout (with the table view filling the view, and the toolbar being pinned to the *bottomLayoutGuide* of the view controller).

As I understood it, navigation bars and toolbars (which are pinned to the bottom of views) should influence the *topLayoutGuide* and *bottomLayoutGuide* of the view controller, and by this influence the *contentInset* of contained scroll views.

The navigation bar is being taken into account (by the *topLayoutGuide* and *automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets*) so that my table view content scrolls underneath it, but is visible below it, but my UIToolBar is not - either by *bottomLayoutGuide* or *automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets*. This behaviour is the same even if I position my toolbar with a frame (not using constraints).

Am I right in thinking that a UIToolBar pinned to the bottom of the view controller's view should be taken into account by the layout guides? If so, does anyone have any ideas as to why it is not?

If not, is there anywhere (amy method) where I can manually add the tollbar frame to the *bottomLayoutGuide* so that it is automatically propagated by *automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets*? And if not, in what method is it best to manually set the table view's content insets?

Comment: Is this the one you added or the one supplied by the navigation bar?

Comment: This was a while ago..., but this was a separate UIToolbar added independently of the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added one yourself it would just be a subview and would not affect the layout guides. Use the built in `UIToolbar` by setting the `UINavigationBar .toobarHidden = false` property. Then set the `UIViewController.toolbarItems = ...`

This toolbar will be your bottom layout guide

Comment: Obviously I've moved on from this now, but I think this is the proper explanation - thank you.